# Requests failed to decode response

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to use python requests to get response from API. In postman this works. I use headers `Content-Type application/json` and in body raw JSON. How I can make this in python?

Now I get the following `contentDecodingError`

```
'Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check')
```

Example Code

```
import requests
url = "http://api.semstorm.com/api-v3/monitoring/monitoring-keyword/get-list"
key = "xxxx"
dat = {'services_token' : key, 'campaign_id' : 43174}
hed = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}


POST = requests.post(url, json = dat, headers = hed)
```

Comment: Have you made POST request in Postman too?

Comment: Your module expects gzip but the server doesn't return gzip.

Comment: In postman I made POST.

Answer (score 1):

Your module expects gzip but the server doesn't return gzip. You could try to add an Encoding-Type. I cannot guarantee the type, this depends on your api.

```
import requests
url = "http://api.semstorm.com/api-v3/monitoring/monitoring-keyword/get-list"
key = "xxxx"
dat = {'services_token' : key, 'campaign_id' : 43174}
hed = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'deflate'}

POST = requests.post(url, json = dat, headers = hed)
```

Comment: In R (library httr) this works if I  add encode = c("json").

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in R if I add encode = c('json').